# Body Background Image doesn't shows with CSS, only in HTML

Tags: html, css

I have a really weird problem. I have tried to use CSS to set the backgorund of the body, but it doesn't allow me. When I'm using the simple HTML tags within the  tag

```
<body background="images/bg.jpg">
```

its WORKING! BUT when I'm using this in CSS:

```
body { 
    background-image: url(../images/bg.jpg);
}
```

It doesn't shows the BG image.

Everything is correct, if I check the folders, everything is in its place. I have tried this in Chrome and Mozilla, but neither of them are working.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is the CSS in a separate file, if so, is it in a different directory to your HTML file?

Comment: Don't forget that the specified path is relative to where the css is located, not the html file

Comment: do you get console errors? maybe about missing resource? my guess is that the path to ../images/ isn't correct.

Comment: I have used DW and I have used it auto-complete feature when inserting the image, so everything should be all right, but its not working :/ I have did the same when I did the body in the HTML file, and that was working...when I do the same in CSS its not working... WHAT t-he HELL IS THIS???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your CSS is inline:

```
<style>
    body { background-image: url('images/bg.jpg'); }
</style>
```

If you're using a file, say `css/main.css`:

```
body { background-image: url('../images/bg.jpg'); }
```

Alternatively, you could use an absolute path:

```
body { background-image: url('/images/bg.jpg'); }
```

This example requires the image directory to be in the root web directory.

Comment: I have did them but noone is working. The directories are good and the files aswell, I have used DW and I have used it auto-complete feature when inserting the image, so everything should be all right, but its not working :/

Comment: Another `body` declaration may be overriding the `background-image` property. Your HTML attribute method would take precedence over any CSS property.

Answer (score 1):

Try `url("./images/bg.jpg")` or `url("/images/bg.jpg")`.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same trouble here. I thought that I tried everything but ... There was one more thing.

Firstly, my css path as followed:

```
assets/css/custom/main.css
```

my image folder as followed:

```
assets/img/bodyBackround.jpg
```

In order to display my backround on the page using css I had to go 2 folders back. Example from my page:

```
body{
  background: url(../../img/bodyBackround.jpg) repeat;
}
```

Where `../../` means go back 2 folders. Hope this helps.

More information can be found here http://jeffreybarke.net/2013/06/paths-and-urls-relative-and-absolute/